# Angular nested subscriptions with forEach loop and setting values of original return

Tags: angular, subscription

Need a little help here please :) I know having a nested subscription within a subscription is a big no no and I am trying to find a way around it but my understanding of maps, merge maps etc is lacking and I am unsure how to correct this mistake.

I am getting a list of all the ADO projects that we have and then I need to cycle through all those ado projects to get a list of all the release pipelines under that ado project.
I then want to set the releasePipline array on that adoProject model to the value I get. So in code looks something like this:

```
  private prefetchData(): void {
    this.callCount = 0;
    this.adoService.getADOProjects()
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
    .subscribe({
      next: (result: any) => { 
        this.adoProjects = result;
        this.getPipelinesAndReleases();
      }, 
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }

  private getPipelinesAndReleases() {
    this.adoProjects.value.forEach(project => {
      this.adoService.getADOProjectPipelines(project.id)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe((pipelines) => {
        project.pipelines = pipelines.value;
        this.callCount++;
        if (this.callCount == this.adoProjects.count) {
          this.openDialog();
        }
      });        
    });
  }
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction please as I am really struggling

Answer (score 2):

The following code from your example implies that you want `openDialog` method to be called when all pipelines requests were successfully resolved.
[forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) could help you with that.

```
if (this.callCount == this.adoProjects.count) {
     this.openDialog();
}
```

Also, [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) will help you to avoid nested subscriptions.

General idea behind updated solution is to:

1. Fetch list of projects
2. Map each project from `adoProjects.value` to Observable (http request). Eventually you'll get array of Observables.
3. Pass array of Observables from step 2 to `forkJoin`.
4. Once `forkJoin` is resolved - call `openDialog` method.

P.S: Errors catching was omitted in my example, but you could easily add [catchError](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/catchError) for each http request you have.

```
class AdoProjectClass {

    constructor(private adoService: AdoService) {}

    private prefetchData(): void {
        this.adoService
            .getADOProjects() // Step 1
            .pipe(
                switchMap((adoProjects: ProjectsResponse) => this.getPipelinesAndReleases(adoProjects))
            )
            .subscribe(() => this.openDialog()); // Step 4
    }
    
    
    private getPipelinesAndReleases(adoProjects: ProjectsResponse): Observable<ProjectPipelines[]> {
        // Step 2
        const pipelines$ = adoProjects.value.map((project: AdoProject) =>
            this.adoService.getADOProjectPipelines(project.id)
                .pipe(
                    tap((pipelines: ProjectPipelines) => project.pipelines = pipelines.value)
                ));
        
        return forkJoin(pipelines$); // Step 3
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - though it doesn't quite work- seem to be an issue with the return types - this is my fault as I didn;t include it in my question. The this.adoService.getADOProjects call returns a type of  'ADOProjects' and the  getAdoProjectReleasePipelines returns a 'ReleasePipelines' object.
The value of the ReleasePipelines is an array which is what I am trying to set to each array item in the project collection